# What event signals that a UserControl is being destroyed?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events, asynchronous

I have a UserControl-derived control the displays some information fetched from a web server. I'm currently in the process of making the initialization of the control asyncronous, to improve responsiveness.

In my Load event handler, I'm creating a CancellationTokenSource, and using the associated Token in the various async calls.

I now want to ensure that if the user closes the form before the async operation completes, the operation will be cancelled. In other words, I want to call Cancel on the token.

I'm trying to figure out *where* to do this. If there was an Unload event that I could trap, then that would be perfect - but there isn't. In fact, I can't find any event that looks suitable.

I *could* trap the close event for the containing Form, but I really wanted to keep everything local to my UserControl.

Suggestions?

Comment: Add a handler to control loaded event in the control constructor after initializeComponent and then use Window.GetWindow(this) and add window.Closing listener

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I suggest the [Control::HandleDestroyed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.control.handledestroyed.aspx) event. It is raised, when the underlying HWnd is destroyed (which usually happens, when the parent form is closed). To handle it in your own UserControl, you should override [OnHandleDestroyed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onhandledestroyed.aspx).

You have full access to the Control's properties at this moment, because it is not yet disposed of.

Comment: I made a similar comment about using the Disposed even (see Mr. Steak's answer). I worry that this event may not be "early" enough, since it may in fact not happen until Dispose is called - since this is an obvious thing for Dispose to do.

Comment: I'm more-or-less persuading myself that I need to do it from the point of view of the form itself, rather than keeping it local to the control...

Comment: Just be careful that this is called when the control is used in the designer. One may want to use if (!DesignMode) in the overrides body.

Comment: @Elmue: It might be the case that `OnHandleDestroyed` is called somehow by `Dispose`. But that is not the point. `Dispose` of an embedded control is called when `Dispose` of the parent is called. When someone does not dispose of a form for some reason then `Dispose` on the user control might be called much later. And that does not match the OP's requirements.

Comment: ATTENTION: If you set ComboBox.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList the handle will be destroyed and created again!

Answer (score 14):

Another solution

```
    protected override void OnParentChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnParentChanged(e);

        if (parentForm != null)
        {
            parentForm.Closing -= parentForm_Closing;
        }
        parentForm = FindForm();

        if (parentForm != null)
            parentForm.Closing += parentForm_Closing;
    }

    void parentForm_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        parentForm.Closing -= parentForm_Closing;
        parentForm = null;
        //closing code
    }
```

Comment: This won't work if control is child of another control - when parent changes the parent form is still null.

Solution is to also handle VisibleChanged event.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use the [`Disposed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.disposed.aspx) event?

When a form is closing, it will call `Dispose` on itself and all child controls will be disposed recursively as well.

Comment: Are you sure, the form will call `Dispose` on child controls when closing? I thought it was under the resposibililty of the calling code to dispose of a `Form`.

Comment: Hmmm... I'm wary of Dispose, because it's never clear exactly when (and indeed whether) it will be called. If it isn't called until the GC gets involved, then that's too late for my purposes.

Comment: Ok, I found it. `Dispose` is automatically called when closing a modeless form. When displaying a modal dialog by calling `Form::ShowDialog()`, the calling code has to do the cleanup (or the garbage collector will do it sooner or later).

Comment: Yeah, that's too many ifs and buts for my liking. I'll change tack, I think. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UserControl.Dispose();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for an event that I could trap that signals to me that the control is being disposed - not for a way to cause it to be disposed.

Comment: The error in the solution above is: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property 'Component.Dispose()'

Comment: @GaryMcGill I think what Gimhan mean is that in the .Designer.cs file you have a dispose method that will be called whenever the parent form the user control is in is closed. In other words you can just ad your code that needs to be run when the UserControl is disposed into this. In case your form is not closed, but the usercontrol is removed from the form, you can call the Dispose() methid directly as Gimhan suggests.

Answer (score 0):

try UserControl_VisibleChange event like if any service is enabled during loading the UserControl like enabled timer or open any port like com1 just check if that service is enabled then run your desired code which will indicate this form is being closed.