# What is the event when closing a UserControl?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a class that inherits from `UserControl`:

```
public partial class MyView : System.Windows.Forms.UserControl
```

I want to handle the event that occurs when the user clicks on the X in the upper right corner. Maybe it is [Form.Closing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closing.aspx)? But I don't see that as an option in the designer. What event is it?

Edit:

[image: Here is a list of all events available in the designer]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to know user has clicked "X" or the "Close" button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683679/how-to-know-user-has-clicked-x-or-the-close-button)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What event signals that a UserControl is being destroyed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12474566/what-event-signals-that-a-usercontrol-is-being-destroyed)

Comment: You can "close" a user control, its lifetime is determined by the Form that it is hosted on.  It raises the Disposed event when it gets destroyed.

Comment: @waka: As I said, Form.Closing is not available.

Comment: OnParenVisibilityChanged can be also used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class SomeControl : UserControl
{
    Form _owner;

    public SomeControl()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnVisibleChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnVisibleChanged(e);

        if (Visible)
        {
            _owner = FindForm();
            //_owner = ParentForm; 
            _owner.FormClosing += _owner_FormClosing;
            _owner.FormClosed += _owner_FormClosed;
        }
    }

    private void _owner_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private void _owner_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Hide();
        _owner.FormClosing -= _owner_FormClosing;
        _owner.FormClosed -= _owner_FormClosed;
        Parent.Controls.Remove(this);
        _owner = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: In my case, `FindForm()` returns null.

Comment: If the control is not (or not yet) added to a form this function will return null.
In the constructor of a control this.FindForm () will return null. Use an event like OnCreateControl to check on which form the control is shown.

Comment: override OnVisibleChanged event handler and there you can get the owner form.

Comment: @AlLelopath A UserControl can use `this.ParentForm` to reference the form that is hosting it.

Comment: This is really close. In `_owner_FormClosing` (or `_owner_FormClosed`), after I do what I need to do, what super method do I have to call to close `SomeControl`?

Comment: @AlLelopath What are you doing?  A control doesn't close.

Comment: When not handling these events myself, clicking on the X closes the control. Now I have the code above, but replacing the `throw` with a `System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine` for the moment and the control does not close, i.e., is not displayed anymore.

Comment: Oops, that should be "i.e., is still displayed."

Comment: see the _owner_FormClosing handler in answer. I edited it again.

Comment: I'm not clears on that code. Could you add it to your answer?

Comment: I'm only using `_owner_FormClosing`, no need for both. Something is still not right. I don't know why but `_owner_FormClosing` is getting called 6 times when clicking the X. There are 20+ components on the control. So I've added an `if (_owner != null)` to guard on the multiple calls. Now the behavior is that `_owner_FormClosing` gets called and the control is *still* displayed. Then on the second click of X, it is not displayed, because the event handler has been removed and it is calling whatever needs to be called to remove it.

Comment: How many UserControls you have on your form? it is not so easy to understand what is going on without code.